# How to pass props to 'screens'/components in react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, inheritance, components

I'm fairly new to programming in general and even newer to JS and React(Native) but I have worked on this for an entire day now and I still haven't figured it out so I have resorted to Stack Overflow in hopes that someone can help me.

Basically what I want to accomplish is to set other `Components` as children of the `App` component because I want them to be able to access information that I will set in the `state` of `App`. However, at the same time, I am also using `react-navigation` to create bottom navigation bars and thus I have no idea on how I can pass `props` of `App` to these other `Components` such as the `ExplorePage` component which is representative of the other `children components`.

App

```js
import React from 'react';
import ExplorePage from './app/tabs/ExplorePage';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

...other imports

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
      parentState: 'testing testing',
    }

}

const MainScreenNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {screen: ExplorePage},
    Search: {screen: SearchPage},
    Favorites: {screen: FavoritesPage},
  }
);


export default MainScreenNavigator;
```

ExplorePage, which is just like SearchPage and FavoritesPage

```js
...imports

export default class ExplorePage extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    }
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.parentState ? this.props.parentState : "Parent state does not exist what do :(");
  }
  
  render(){
    return(
    <Text>Testing</Text>
    )
  }
```

And obviously every time the console prints that `parentState` does not exist. I thought that being in the same place would give the other `components` like `ExplorePage` props of `App`. Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could pass a props using function. Try this

```
import React from 'react';
import ExplorePage from './app/tabs/ExplorePage';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

...other imports

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
      parentState: 'testing testing',
    }

  render() {

     // old
     // const MainScreenNavigator = mainScreenNavigator(this.state.parentState);
     const MainScreenNavigator = mainScreenNavigator(this.state);

     return (
         <MainScreenNavigator />
     )


  }

}

const mainScreenNavigator = value => createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    // Home: { screen : props => <ExplorePage {...props} parentState={value} /> },
    Home: { screen : props => <ExplorePage {...props} {...value} /> },
    Search: {screen: SearchPage},
    Favorites: {screen: FavoritesPage},
  }
);


export default App;
```

**Edit**

First thing, I changed your `MainScreenNavigator` to be a function, as it is accepting state values dynamically.

Second thing, Instead of directly assigning `{ screen : Component }`, I used function. This is the feature provided by reactnavigation. You can find about this in the documentation. [ReactNavigation](http://reactnavigation.org)

If you want to pass multiple attributes then you can use es6 spread operator, as shown in the edit. `{...value}`, this will pass all the property of value to that component.

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much it worked. Could you mind explaining a little bit about what you did and why it works? Btw I removed the {} curly brackets around Home to make it work otherwise it gives a syntax error

Comment: Also is there a way to assign `ExplorePage` every single variable from `App`'s state or is the only way to individually assign?

Comment: Haha! I forgot about that `{}` curly brackets.. fixed in edit.. see in the edit about how I have passed the multiple params

Answer (score 23):

for those who are looking for a React Navigation 5 solution, you can use `initialParams` like this:

```
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen
    name="screenName"
    component={screenComponent}
    initialParams={{key: value}}
  />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: This also works in React Navigation 6.

Comment: initialParams add navigation params (useRoute -> route.params), but not react component "props"

Answer (score 2):

You should use Navigator Props "screenProps" as mentionned in API:

> **screenProps** - Pass down extra options to child screens

On child screen, just take props via `this.props.screenProps`

Comment: more information: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#navigator-props, yet they are planing to get rid of screenProps: https://github.com/react-navigation/rfcs/pull/5

Comment: They got rid of `screenProps`.